# Unimplemented SQL generation for predicate in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am getting the following error in the core data

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unimplemented SQL generation for predicate (mRemainderId LIKE <MSaveRemainders: 0x1740cae90>
```

And below is the code which i have used

```
  -(void) deleteRemainders:(NSMutableArray*) deleteArray{
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MSaveRemainders" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    for (NSString *remainderId in deleteArray) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mRemainderId LIKE %@", remainderId];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
        [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in fetchedObjects) {
            [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
        }
    }

}
```

Delete array contains

(entity: MSaveRemainders; id: 0xd000000000040002  ; data: {
    furtherSubCategoryId = nil;
    mDate = "2016-05-10";
    mNote = "this is financial";
    mNumberOfGlasses = 6;
    mRemainderId = 1462793810;
    mRepeat = None;
    mRepeatDays = "";
    mSleepTime = "10:00 PM";
    mSnooze = No;
    mTime = "(\n    \"05:06 pm\"\n)";
    mTitle = financial;
    mTone = "";
    mWakeUpTime = "06:00 AM";
    mWaterInLitres = "1.6";
    mYourWeight = 50;
    mainCategoryId = 1;
    subCategoryId = "(null)";
})

Comment: your `deleteArray ` will hold only `strings` ? or it's holding other objects ?

Comment: It seems that `remainderId` is a `MSaveRemainders` object and not a `NSString`. You maybe be looking for `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mRemainderId LIKE %@", remainderId.mRemainderId]` instead.

Comment: @mortgySee the edited question containing delete array

Comment: @mortgy See the edited question containing delete array

Comment: @Larme See the edited question containing delete array

Comment: ok , you can try the code i mentioned in answer, is your `data` object is a model property ? if it is, you can comment the `NSPredicate` line and uncomment the line in comment block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're trying to access NSString in array which doesn't contain NSString, your array contains only `MSaveRemainders`
so you should get the objects of kind of `MSaveRemainders` and check it's properties,
your method should look like the following

```
-(void) deleteRemainders:(NSMutableArray*) deleteArray{
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MSaveRemainders" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    for (MSaveRemainders *savedReminder in deleteArray) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mRemainderId LIKE %@", [savedReminder.data valueForKey:@"mRemainderId"]];

        // or like the follwing if "data" is a property of a class ( model )
        /*
         NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mRemainderId LIKE %@", savedReminder.data.mRemainderId ];

         */
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
        [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in fetchedObjects) {
            [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what s data in [savedReminder.data valueForKey:@"mRemainderId"]

Comment: what is type of `data` property ?

as you paste here `(entity: MSaveRemainders; id: 0xd000000000040002 ; data: { furtherSubCategoryId = nil; ...` 

your MSaveRemainders contains 2 properties , `id` and `data`
data seems to be related to different model, so what is `data` property type ?